# Unable install Django through Dockerfile

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, pip

when I run 'docker build .' command,
"ERROR: Invalid requirement: 'Django=>4.0.4' (from line 1 of /requirements.txt)
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

this error shows up. I have upgraded pip to the latest version. When I check version of pip , it shows 22.1.
But when I run docker build command again, nothing changes.
I have upgraded from this /usr/local/bin/python location. but still nothing changed.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, python version is 3.8.

my docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine
MAINTAINER Kanan App Developer

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

requirements.txt file:

```
Django=>4.0.4
djangorestframework=>3.13.1
```

Comment: can you please share the dockerfile you are trying to build?

Comment: Can you `pip install -r requirements.txt` into a new empty virtual environment, without Docker?  (Do you need to spell the version constraint `>=` and not `=>`?)

Comment: @DavidMaze with virtual environment I can install. But when I use Dockerfile the error shows up.

Comment: @Simon I added docker file to my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**=>** is not a valid realtional operator for greater than or equal to.

The valid operator is **>=**. So, your requirements.txt file should be:

```
Django>=4.0.4
djangorestframework>=3.13.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use == or >= instead => in your requirements.txt, like this

```
Django==4.0.4
djangorestframework==3.13.1
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I didn't pay attention.